# Getting errors while using ODE45 Matlab Package

Tags: matlab, math, ode

I am new to matlab, and am trying to implement RungaKutta Method to solve Third Order simultaneous differential equations using ODE45. The below code has been written taking assistance through online available articles and papers. I am getting the following errors. Can someone please take a look?

The set of equations I am trying to solve are: [image: Set of equations]

*File: freeconvect.m*

```
function Y=freeconvect(eta,X,Pr,Le)
% X=(F0; F1; F2; Theta0; Theta1; Phi0; Phi1)
Nb=0;
Nt=0;
dF0deta=X(2);
df1deta=X(3);
dF2deta=((X(2))^2)-(X(1)*X(3));%-3*X(1)*X(3)+2*(X(2))^2-X(4);
dTheta0deta=X(5);
%dTheta1deta=((-1)*Pr)*((X(1)*X(5))+(Nb*X(7)*X(5))+(Nt*(X(7))^2));%-3*Pr*X(1)*X(5);
dPhi0deta=X(7);
dPhi1deta=(-1)*((Le*X(1)*X(5))+((Nt/Nb)*((-1)*Pr)*((X(1)*X(5))+(Nb*X(7)*X(5))+(Nt*        (X(7))^2))));%-3*Pr*X(1)*X(5);
Y=[dF0deta; dF1deta; dF2deta; dTheta0deta; dPhi0deta; dPhi1deta];
```

*File: Untitled3.m*

```
% ODE45 Solver for freeconvect.m
Pr=10;
Le=10;
etaspan=[0 10] ;
Xinit=[0;1;1;1;1;1;1];
[Eta,X]=ode45(@freeconvect,etaspan,Xinit,Pr,Le);
plot(Eta,X);
```

*ERROR-------------------------------------------------------*

```
>> Untitled3
Attempted to access X(7); index out of bounds because numel(X)=6.

Error in freeconvect (line 10)
dPhi0deta=X(7);

Error in odearguments (line 88)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 114)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in Untitled3 (line 10)
[Eta,X]=ode45(@freeconvect,etaspan,Xinit,Pr,Le);
```

Comment: +1 for a 3rd order ODE. First time I saw one posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `ode45` is the right tool for this problem. `ode45` is designed to solve [initial value problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem). Based your "boundary conditions" you have a [boundary value problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem). As far as Matlab goes, [start here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/boundary-value-problems.html).

The error you're getting is due to this line in your `freeconvect` function:

```
dPhi0deta=X(7);
```

According to the comments at the top `X(7)` is `Phi1`, but you've only specified `Xinit` with six values.

Comment: I have seen a similar type of problem solved using ODE45 in a research paper. They didnot mention the way it was done, but ODE45 was mentioned.

Comment: @user1675947: Well, the [shooting method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) is one way to convert a BVP to an IVP. Your bounds at `Inf` may cause issues regardless.